# Comparing Boolean Value

Tags: java, gwt, comparison, boolean, conditional-statements

I have a checkBox named as testCheck. When user check this the value becomes TRUE. I am able to implement the compare of the TRUE/FALSE with the following ways

1.

```
if (testCheck.getValue() == Boolean.TRUE) {

   // Respective Code

}
```

2.

```
if (testCheck.getValue().equals(Boolean.TRUE)) {

   //Respective Code
}
```

3.

```
if (testCheck.getValue()) {

   //Respective Code
 }
```

My questions:

- Is there any difference ?
- If yes, Which one is the best way of implementation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends....

if the return type of `testCheck.getValue()` is `boolean`, the 3rd one is ok.

But if it was `Boolean` (Big B), I would do:

```
Boolean.TRUE.equals(testCheck.getValue())
```

to avoid the NPE during autoboxing.

Answer (score 4):

The answers:

- There's no difference for *compiler*: a good *optimizer* will generate the *same code*. But there's difference for *human beings* (developers, testers, supporters etc): it's *readability*.
- The 3d option is *far more natural* and that's why *easier to read*.

So the expected code (***least surprise principle***) is

```
  if (testCheck.getValue()) {
    ...
    //Respective Code
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer 3rd option. It's elegant. Since the `testCheck.getValue()` evaluated to boolean, you can use it inside the if condition

In java, with `==` operator, we are checking two reference are referring same object in memory.

To check two object are meaningfully equal, use `.equals()` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
Is there any difference ?
```

There is only a difference in readability.

```
If yes, Which one is the best way of implementation ?
```

The last one is probably the way to go if you want your code to be read and understood fast.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any difference ?

Yes, there is.

If yes, Which one is the best way of implementation ?

3rd one.

Comment: If everyone answered like you, I don't think people would learn much on SO. Yes/No answers are not very helpful in the long run, if there is no *why*.